# url re writing in .htaccess in codeigniter app

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a codeigniter app and i wanted to remove index.php from the URI. so from the codeigniter wiki i used this script.

It stopped working once i change a config, after this change all my urls only returned home page. No matter what link i used, it only gives me the home page of my site. So i reverted it back to index.php but the server still works the same way. I tried deleting the .htacess file completely then update it with the new one which actually works but even then its working the same way. (all urls redirected to home page) Im totally out of clue, on whats wrong with my script or server.

P.S : when using .htacess i did make $config["index"] to be blank.

UPDATE

Now i removed everything else from my .htaccess file and i have only this which is the essential part to remove index.php from uri segment

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Even with only these all my urls are taking me only to the home page. I am clueless as of whats happening.

Comment: What is your server platform?  Have you tried altering the `uri_protocol` setting in config.php?  Also, it wouldn't hurt to show your routes.php if there's anything wonky there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app/config/config.php try changing the value of:

`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`

to:

`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';`

If still not working, try the remaining options (PATH_INFO, QUERY_STRING, ORIG_PATH_INFO).

Answer (score 0):

Your ErrorDocument line is inside `<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>` which to me looks like you don't have the mod_rewrite module installed. (If you did, that line would be ignored.) The `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` line is a hack to get you to the /index.php file in case a request comes in for a file that doesn't exist.

To set the 404 page in CodeIgnitor, you need to edit your `routes.php` file.

```
$route['404_override'] = 'general/not_found';
```

[More details.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Ive already did that. Ive already set it there. Also i am sure the mod_rewrite is installed, i checked up the config, and also if u had missed, this thing worked until i changed some config, then reverted it back.

Comment: If changing the ErrorDocument line has any effect at all, your mod_rewrite module is not installed properly.

Comment: Also, if your rewrite rules are working properly, there would be no reason to have an ErrorDocument line. The two rewritecond lines that check for `!-d` and `!-f` will match any request that doesn't exist on the file system.

Comment: i completely removed the last three lines and still it has the same effect